# Granting all permissions on all tables in a database to a user in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

I have created a database `foo` and tables `bar1` and `bar2` in this database. I am trying to grant all permissions on these tables to a user `myuser` - specifically DML.

I created the user as follows:

```
yugabyte=# CREATE USER myuser
```

I have also created the database and the corresponding tables in it as the root user.

First, I tried the following but this did not help:

```
yugabyte=# GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database foo to user myuser;
```

Next, per some postgresql steps, I tried the following. This did not work as well.

```
yugabyte=# GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO myuser;
```

I am guessing that my table is not in the `public` schema? Or is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO myuser;` on database `foo`. From the above snippet, it looks like you're running it on database `yugabyte`.

This should work:

```
yugabyte=# \c foo
You are now connected to database "foo" as user "yugabyte".
foo=# grant all privileges on all tables in schema public to myuser;
GRANT
foo=# set role myuser;
SET
fooo=> insert into hello values(1),(2);
INSERT 0 2
```